# LDAP groups authentication fails: Invalid Binding Information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication, devise, ldap

I'm using [devise_ldap_authenticatable](https://github.com/cschiewek/devise_ldap_authenticatable) to log in into my Rails app via LDAP. Log in works for user (with username), but does not work for groups: when I try to check if user is in a particular group I get:

> 'Net::LDAP::BindingInformationInvalidError in
>   Devise::SessionsController#create
>
> Invalid binding information
>
> Extracted source (around line #244):
>   raise Net::LDAP::BindingInformationInvalidError, "Invalid binding information" unless (user && psw)

I tried several suggested solutions but they all failed with the error mentioned above.

### First attempted solution

I tried changing `config.ldap_check_group_membership=false` to `config.ldap_check_group_membership=true` in `devise.rb`:

```
config.ldap_create_user = true
config.ldap_check_group_membership = true
config.ldap_check_attributes = false
config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = false
config.ldap_ad_group_check = true (also tried false with this one)
```

and setting groups in `ldap.yml` file like this:

```
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
    group_base: OU=US,DC=um,DC=com #also tried without group_base, with group_base DC=um,DC=com
    required_groups:
        - CN=D US Workers,OU=Workers,OU=abc,OU=US,DC=um,DC=com
        - CN=B US Workers,OU=Workers,OU=abc,OU=US,DC=um,DC=com
```

later like that:

```
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
    #also tried without group_base, with group_base DC=um,DC=com
    group_base: OU=US,DC=um,DC=com 
    required_groups:
        ["memberOf", "CN=D US  Workers,OU=Workers,OU=abc,OU=US,DC=um,DC=com;CN=B US Workers,OU=Workers,OU=abc,OU=US,DC=um,DC=com"]
```

### Second attempted solution

After this failed, I also tried changing `ldap_check_attributes=false` to `ldap_check_attributes=true` in `devise.rb`:

```
config.ldap_create_user = true
config.ldap_check_group_membership = false
config.ldap_check_attributes = true
config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = false
```

and setting attribute in `ldap.yml` file like this:

```
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
    require_attribute:
        memberOf: CN=D US Workers,OU=Workers,OU=abc,OU=US,DC=um,DC=com
development:
    host: <%= ENV["LDAP_HOST"] %>
    port: <%= ENV["LDAP_PORT"] %>
    attribute: 'userprincipalname'
    base: 'DC=um,DC=com' 
    ssl: <%= ENV["LDAP_SSL"] %>
    <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
```

I have access to AD, I know, that group is correct. When I look at my account there, I see something like this:

```
memberOf:  CN=D US Workers,OU=Workers,OU=abc,OU=US,DC=um,DC=com;CN=B US
       Workers,OU=Workers,OU=abc,OU=US,DC=um,DC=com
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I managed to find one solution that worked. I've changed `devise.rb` file like this:

```
 config.ldap_create_user = true
 config.ldap_check_group_membership = false
 config.ldap_check_attributes = true
 config.ldap_use_admin_to_bind = false
```

and `ldap.yml` like that:

```
authorizations: &AUTHORIZATIONS
    #group_base:
    #required_groups:
    require_attribute:
        memberOf: CN=D US Workers,OU=Workers,OU=abc,OU=US,DC=um,DC=com

development:
    host: <%= ENV["LDAP_HOST"] %>
    port: <%= ENV["LDAP_PORT"] %>
    attribute: sAMAccountName
    base: DC=um,DC=com
    ssl: <%= ENV["LDAP_SSL"] %>
    admin_user: <%= ENV["LDAP_ADMIN_USER"] %> # currently my own: CN=name surname,OU=Workers,OU=abc,OU=US,DC=um,DC=com
    admin_password: <%= ENV["LDAP_ADMIN_PASSWORD"] %> currently my own password
    <<: *AUTHORIZATIONS
```

If I find better solution, I'll post it. Feel free to suggest your way too.