# Why ldap bind is failing on server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ldap

I'm authenticating against LDAP server in my rails application,
the code below is working locally but not on the server.

On the server it throws `Net::LDAP::BindingInformationInvalidError (Invalid binding information)` when trying to login in the app but **works through the console**

I'm pretty new to Ruby and can't figure out the proper way to debug it... I know the LDAP configuration is right because i can authenticate and bind from the console or on my local development environment.. I tried to pass `:verbose => true` to the LDAP constructor but without effect...

```
require 'net/ldap'
require 'devise/strategies/authenticatable'

module Devise
  module Strategies
    class LdapAuthenticatable < Authenticatable
      def authenticate!
        if params[:user]
          ldap = Net::LDAP.new :host => 'XX.XX.XX.XX',
            :port => 636,
            :connect_timeout => 5,
            :base => 'CN=Configuration,DC=internal,DC=XX,DC=XX',
            :encryption => {
                :method => :simple_tls
            },
            :auth => {
              :method => :simple,
              :username => ENV['LDAP_USER'],
              :password => ENV['LDAP_PASSWORD']
            }

          result = ldap.bind_as(:base => "OU=Users,OU=XX,DC=XX,DC=XX,DC=XX",
                              :filter => "(userPrincipalName=#{email})",
                              :password => password,
          )

          if result
            user = User.find_by(email: email)
            success!(user)
          else
            return fail(:invalid_login)
          end
        end
      end

      def email
        params[:user][:email]
      end

      def password
        params[:user][:password]
      end

    end
  end
end

Warden::Strategies.add(:ldap_authenticatable, Devise::Strategies::LdapAuthenticatable)
```

---

### SOLVED

turned out it was the ENV variables that were not read.

Comment: As you are new to Ruby the two things that helped me the most were `binding.pry` and `inspect`. You can do `puts result.inspect` and it will give you a dump of information on result. `binding.pry` will let you enter your code anywhere you put it, you will need to have `pry` installed as well. IMO you should always use `pry` over the default ruby console. https://pryrepl.org/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that account is not authorized? Sounds like the problem is in the binding configuration: `base => "OU=Users,OU=XX,DC=XX,DC=XX,DC=XX"`

More information from other users who encountered this error:

- https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/21937
- [LDAP groups authentication fails: Invalid Binding Information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631524/ldap-groups-authentication-fails-invalid-binding-information)